# Как скрыть второй Label?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]
У меня в cell есть два label. Мне нужно спрятать второй label, и я это делаю через свойство hidden.

Второй label прячется, но текст так и остается в верхней части сell.

Очень нужен совет, как сделать расположение текста по середине cell по высоте.

Comment: Может текст в верхней части остаеться, потому что это другой label?

Comment: Ну я ж и спрашиваю как при закрытии второго label розтянуть первый на весь cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[label2 setHidden: YES];

CGRect frame = label1.frame;
frame.size.height = cell.frame.size.height;
[label1 setFrame: frame];
```

Если высота label будет равна высоте cell, то текст label будет по середине cell

Comment: к сожалению ето не помогло

Comment: label1 растягивается?

Comment: к сожалению нет

Comment: тогда такой вариант: на 1 вьюху кидаешь эти лейбы, на другую виюху кидаешь 1 лейб и растягиваешь по высоте. И потом просто одну вьюху скрываешь, а другую показываешь. Немного overhead, но так тоже делают

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать Autolayout.

Для начала нужно создать IBOutlet для Height Constraint у нижнего Label.

[image: Создаем IBOutlet]

Далее в коде изменяем параметр constant у созданного аутлета.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomViewHeightConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0;
}

@end
```

Если необходимо изменять данный параметр в процессе работы, то нужно будет отправить сообщение

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sergei Stralenia натолкнул меня на решение этого задания.
Я на свой уже существующий cell сделал еще один третий label который я разтянул полностью на весь cell потом с помощью hidden  спрятал два предыдущих cell, так я и добился результата 
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно центрировать label используя `cell.frame.height/2`:

```
label1.hidden = YES;
label2.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x, cell.frame.height/2);
```